# Connect CouchDB with asp.net C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, couchdb

How to connect couchDB with ASP.NET C# application? If any one can you give a sample application.

Comment: Does this help? https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_C%23

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need and after evaluating the options available, to meet the requirements of my application, I created any components that helped me a lot and maybe they can help you and also others. I make it clear that I have no intention of promoting myself here, just sharing something that may be useful.

The detailed explanation of how to configure and use it is on [Github](https://github.com/wquintanilhadasilva/CouchDb.Repository/blob/master/doc.pdf).

Link: [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CouchDb.Repository.Helper/) |
[Github](https://github.com/wquintanilhadasilva/CouchDb.Repository)

Example of use for retrieving documents with mango-querie:

```
IList<User> users;
var sts = new List<String> { "ACTIVE", "LOCKED" };
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    var query = db.FindOf("list-status", new { id = "OwnerIdloop.user.7", statuses = sts });
    users = db.List<User>(query);
}
Array.ForEach(users.ToArray(), Console.WriteLine);
```

Example of adding documents:

```
User user = createUser("email@email.com");
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    var result = db.Insert<User>(user); // add document and return instance changed with operation revision id
    Console.WriteLine(result.Revision);
}
```

Example of changing documents:

```
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    // Load document data by ID
    var user = db.Get<User>("email@email.com");
    user.Name = user.Name + "::CHANGED";

    var result = db.Update<User>(user); // update document and return instance changed with operation revision id
    Console.WriteLine(result.Revision);
}
```

Example of deleting documents:

```
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    // Load document data by ID
    var user = db.Get<User>("email@email.com");

    var result = db.Delete<User>(user); // delete document from database. Return true case sucess or false case not deleted
    Console.WriteLine($"Sucesso: {result}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing the NuGet, just create an instance of MyCouch.Client and pass it the URL of your database.

```
using (var client = new MyCouchClient("http://127.0.0.1:5984/test"))
{
    //Consume here
}
```

The format is: `{scheme}://[{username}:{password}]/{authority}/{localpath}`. From v0.11.0, there's a specific MyCouchUriBuilder that you can use for building the Uri. It will automatically e.g. apply `Uri.EscapeDataString` to username and password when calling `SetBasicCredentials`.

```
var uriBuilder = new MyCouchUriBuilder("http://localhost:5984/")
    .SetDbName(TestConstants.TestDbName)
    .SetBasicCredentials("foob@r", "p@ssword");

return new MyCouchClient(uriBuilder.Build());
```

For more details [Click Here](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/wiki/documentation#get-connected)